# android ArrayMap throws java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]

Tags: java, android

I  use `android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap`

like this

```
ArrayMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> group = new ArrayMap<>();
```

but I call `ArrayMap.put(key,value)`

throws `ClassCastException` in the `allocArrays(final int size)` method.

```
 private void allocArrays(final int size) {
    if (size == (BASE_SIZE*2)) {
        synchronized (ArrayMap.class) {
            if (mTwiceBaseCache != null) {
                final Object[] array = mTwiceBaseCache;
                mArray = array;
                mTwiceBaseCache = (Object[])array[0];
                mHashes = (int[])array[1];
                array[0] = array[1] = null;
                mTwiceBaseCacheSize--;
                if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Retrieving 2x cache " + mHashes
                        + " now have " + mTwiceBaseCacheSize + " entries");
                return;
            }
        }
    } else if (size == BASE_SIZE) {
        synchronized (ArrayMap.class) {
            if (mBaseCache != null) {
                final Object[] array = mBaseCache;
                mArray = array;
                mBaseCache = (Object[])array[0];
                mHashes = (int[])array[1];
                array[0] = array[1] = null;
                mBaseCacheSize--;
                if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Retrieving 1x cache " + mHashes
                        + " now have " + mBaseCacheSize + " entries");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    mHashes = new int[size];
    mArray = new Object[size<<1];
}
```

app crashes at this line   `mBaseCache = (Object[])array[0];`

very Thanks !!!

Comment: throws   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]

Comment: Your code is so messedup dude.

Comment: mBaseCache is an object or an Array of object ?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with ArrayMap. mBaseCache and array are both Object[]. You're trying to cast a single Object that happens to be a String to a Object[]

Comment: mBaseCache is ArrayMap cache Array  is object[]  type @AhlemJarrar

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the problem is that Multi-Thread.

this bug be fixed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37114373 
update support V25.4.0 is fixed

Comment: @yangil is it fixed yet?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to walk around this issue:

```
    private void fixArrayMapIssue() {
            try {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    Field mBaseCacheSize = ArrayMap.class.getDeclaredField("mBaseCacheSize");
                    mBaseCacheSize.setAccessible(true);
                    mBaseCacheSize.set(null, 100);

                    Field mTwiceBaseCacheSize = ArrayMap.class.getDeclaredField("mTwiceBaseCacheSize");
                    mTwiceBaseCacheSize.setAccessible(true);
                    mTwiceBaseCacheSize.set(null, 100);
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

run the method above when application `onCreate`